# iOS app promote physic product

Tags: ios, app-store, in-app-purchase

I have an idea about marketing. Now I have a candy-crash like game. Whenever users get 10,000 points, they can get 10% off if they buy our physical product. Is my idea illegal in app review?

Anyone feedback is appreciated.

Comment: I don't think it's illegal, I've seen a "tiny wings" like game that give gifts and discounts to players.

Answer (score 0):

If you are selling a digital good it MUST be through in-app-purchases.  However if it is a real world good you can present a coupon inside the app.
See the app guidelines: https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html
section 11

Comment: Yeah, there's nothing to stop you giving them a discount code or something that is tied to their email address or some such mechanic like that.